# equivalent vs equivalence

Tags: equivalence

Which of the following is acceptable?

1. That is a big dog. Its equivalent in size is a goat.
2. That is a big dog. Its equivalence in size is a goat.

Comment: Look up the two words (eg 'equivalent' at [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/equivalent): Noun, sense 1).

Answer (score 1):

1 is closest, but not quite right.

> That is a big dog. It's equivalent in size to a goat.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the wiki subsections for 'equivalence' and 'equivalent'. 
[See here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence)

As will see, the usage of 'equivalence' is quite field specific, e.g. in Chemistry, maths, music etc.

However, 'equivalent' is much more general and can be (and is much often used in every day language).

Hence your first sentence is (more) correct, although as Greg pointed out, there's something just quite not right. I would propose the following:

"That is a big dog. Its size is equivalent to that of a goat."

An example of the usage of 'equivalence' is in logic, and hence quite field-specific, but here's a shot:

All right angle triangles are of the same equivalence class.

I suppose you could rewrite your sentence to be something like:

The size of that dog is in the same equivalence class as goats.

However it still just doesn't fit quite right because the context is all wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I think that (1) is technically correct, but odd. The sentence suggested by Greg is better. (2) is definitely wrong.

If you want to use that particular sentence structure then perhaps "Its equal in size is a goat", but it's still odd. I think the reason it sounds strange is because it implies that if I ask you "What is the dog's equal in size?" you will be able to definitively answer "a goat" - i.e. there is no other correct answer; nothing else is equal in size to this dog.